# Laravel - eager loading filtering related model on different database instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent, filtering

i'm trying to implement filtering as defined [here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/council/tree/master/app/Filters).

This works (to filter model A from controller A), however controller A/model A has a relation to model B, which is what I want to filter, as well as a 3rd relationship to model C from model B.

Model A is hosted on DB instance 1, Model B is hosted on DB instance 2 and are totally separated.
These relationships, without any filters, work fine.

Trying to mess around, I tried something like the below, which clearly does not work, however will hopefully illustrate what i'm trying to do. This filter gets applied to model A

```
protected function sn($sn)
{
    $s= Bid::where('crm', function ($query) {
        $query->where('sNumber', '=', 'SN512345');
    })->get();

    return $s;
}
```

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'crm'. (SQL: select * from [bids] where [crm] = (select * where [sNumber] = SN512345))

Bid is model A/controller A, CRM is model B which is the one I want to filter.

I thought about having numerous different functions in the model to filter, however I don't know if this was the best solution and I thought it was better to get it all out into another class.

I tried the below, which does not work as it applies the query to DB1.

```
$s= Bid::with('crm')->whereHas('crm', function ($query) {
        $query->where('sNumber', '=', 'SN512345');
    })->get();
```

> [SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Opportunity'. (SQL: select * from [bids] where exists (select * from [Opportunity] where [bids].[crm_ref] = [Opportunity].[sNumber] and [sNumber] = SN512345))

Is there a way to implement this in some coherent and reusable way? I was thinking something along the lines of load Bid::, load CRM:: with applied filters, then append CRM:: to Bid:: somehow in the normal way that Eloquent would do this.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I am using the following filter in BidFilter.php
`protected function sn($sn)
    {
        $users = DB::connection('sqlsrv_crm')->table('OpportunityBase')->select('*')->where('new_SalesNumber', '=', $sn)->get();
        return $users;
    }`

And this filters the result set, as I can see in the debug bar:
[debug bar queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqzLH.png)

However this is also loading the normal unfiltered eager loaded CRM relationship. How can I switch to the filtered CRM results instead of the default unfiltered?

BidController index method:

```
public function index(BidFilter $filters)
{
        $bids = $this->getBids($filters);
        return view('public.bids.index', compact('bids'));
}
```

BidFilter

```
    public function index(BidFilter $filters)
{
        $bids = $this->getBids($filters);
        return view('public.bids.index', compact('bids'));
}
```

Comment: I do not think this is possible. You can set up a relationship that spans across multiple databases on the same server, but have never tried, nor do I think it would work, across multiple servers, unless it's some kind of a cluster. Think about how this would work even in theory - eloquent would have to make two separate requests to two different sql servers, then combine the results into a single set, based on query builder. This is not a standard use-case and I do not think there's a built in solution to this.

Comment: Hi, interaction between the two DB instances works fine normally. It's only when trying to introduce some sort of filtering that  this gets confused.

Comment: `Bind::find(1)->crm` would probably work, since it is only interacting with one database server at a time (first, to retrieve Bind model, then to retrieve crm relationship). Does `with('crm')` eager loading work too without the `whereHas`?

Comment: Eager loading (with) will work since it uses a separate query to load the related data, but whereHas can't.  There's no way  to have a single query run across two instances.

Comment: The unfiltered eager loading works fine. I have the separate connections defined in each model file, e.g. protected $connection = 'sqlsrv1'; in one model file, protected $connection = 'sqlsrv2'; in the other file.

Doing $bid->crm etc works fine. However now I  need to implement some sort of filtering against the CRM model.